# Configure python sub-packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, setup.py

I'm trying to set sub-packages for a python project. Please refer to the structure below. The main setup.py will call "setup.py" in each sub packages.

```
my_project
├── my_sub_package1
│   ├── foo2.py
│   ├── foo.py
│   └── setup.py
├── my_sub_package2
│   ├── bar2.py
│   ├── bar.py
│   └── setup.py
└── setup.py [main]
```

With this structure, in other projects, if the user only needs a sub_package, the user can choose to install "my_sub_package1" only, instead of installing the whole package (which can become bulky over time as number of packages increases).

Does anyone know if this is the correct way of doing it? Thanks!